# How can I create native like material Design in cordova angular

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-material

I am trying to create an android app using cordova where I want to implement material design for that I have created an app using angular material but. It is not working like an app. I have a slider menu which look like android drawer but it do not work on slide click like an android app do. And one more query top bar how to match it like the color of action bar.

Here my question is is it possible to create a look and feel like actual material desing of android?

Comment: Try ionic. Its quite similar or try getmdl.io

Comment: Gary is it possible to create an UI like ionic in cor angular

Comment: Angular is a js framework. Material is a UI/css related thing. Two different things. So no. But have resources to merge both

Comment: Gary I can create an app uisng cordova and angular material but it is not behaving like a native android app drawer is there any way I can do this in cordova angular or should I use native.

Comment: That may be cordova or your implementation or css. Can you detail it

Comment: I am opening a cordova app using angular + angular material inside android app usiong cordova run android. I want that to be like a pure native like design like when I touch and open it should open a slide or drawer but onclick it happens. Is it possible to create that kind of feature using angular cordova. Or should I use android native app using java.

Comment: Java is always better for sure. However you might have an isue of touch or tap events. Ensure you have handled that. Generally clicks work. If this is not the issue, explain exactly what is happening. If you are looking for drawer panel that is there in materializecss website try that

Comment: in cordova can we use touch or tap event if yes please provide some link